# Escaping brackets inside driver.execute_script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Webdriver cannot find an element so I would like to do something in general form:

```
def is_checked(driver, xpath):
    checked = driver.execute_script(
"""function getElementByXpath(path) {{return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}}
return getElementByXpath({xpath}).checked;""".format(xpath=xpath)
    )
    return checked
```

but I get `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected token '}'`

without `{{` I get `KeyError: 'return document'`

Escaping { with \ doesn't seem to work either and I would prefer not to hardcode each path and end up with a zillion functions.

There must be a way to make both python and java script happy.

EDIT: I have found a workaround, execute_script can accept additional argument(s) that can then be called inside js with arguments[]

Comment: I have found a workaround, execute_script can accept additional argument(s) that can then be capped inside js

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape those braces too in line: `return getElementByXpath({xpath}).checked;`

Escaping curly braces in multiline is done as you said by doubling them `{{ }}`

Comment: In that case I get xpath not defined as escaping it prevents it from actualy being formated.

Comment: No bad my friend, somehow you answer even thou wrong made me remeber I can pass arguments to javascript directly and avoid formatting altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages aren't xml. you almost always want to use css and document.querySelector:

```
checked = driver.execute_script("""
  return document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]')?.checked
""")
```

note the optional chaining ? after the function, this will prevent crashing when it's not there.